# Get values from same class buttons

Tags: javascript, class, button, click, buttonclick

I have a problem with this script.
I don't understand why Javascript doesn't recognize pdb[i].

```
let pbd=document.getElementsByClassName('pbda');

for (var i=0;i<pbd.length;i++) {
  pbd[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
    let xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (this.readyState==4&&this.status==200) {
        document.getElementById('obxs').style.display='flex';
        document.getElementById('obxd').innerHTML=this.responseText;
      };
    };
    xhttp.open('POST','/ajax/orderdetails',true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send('oid='+pbd[i].value);
  })
};
```

Error is -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your attached event listener **actually runs**, `i` has become `pbd.length`. So you are accessing an element which is not defined in your `pbd` array.

If you want to access an element in **its** event handler, you can use `this`.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".man");
for(var i = 0 ; i < buttons.length;i++){
buttons[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
console.log(this);
console.log(i);
});
}
```

```html
<button class="man">A</button>
<button class="man">B</button>
<button class="man">C</button>
<button class="man">D</button>
<button class="man">E</button>
```

Also you could have replaced `var` with `let`. let is block scoped so the `i` referred is the `i` from that iteration.